# Delete files using Fdelete with Macro Variable containing filepaths

Tags: sas

I am trying to amend the below code from SAS documentation so that I can delete multiple excel files in a directory after they are created and sent via email.

```
    data _null_;
       fname="tempfile";
       rc=filename(fname, &FP.);
       if rc = 0 and fexist(fname) then
          rc=fdelete(fname);
       rc=filename(fname);
    run;
```

Can the above be amended to take file paths from a Macro Variable? e.g, %let FP = '' '' '' etc?

I am having trouble and keep getting error stating that an arithmetic operator is needed. Any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: Try `rc=filename(fname, "&FP");` or `rc=filename(fname, symget("FP"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot. No luck.. it runs without any issues, but the files are still there. Do the paths need to be assigned to FP in a certain way? I am just separating the paths by a space. e.g., %let FP = "/mypath/mypath" "/mypath1/mypath1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `FP` contains a folder name you will have to loop over a directory, reading each filename and processing as necessary.

Example:

When `filename` is called with the first argument a blank valued variable, SAS will create (compute) a unique fileref value and return it in the variable, which can then be used in further processing.  The computed fileref will not collide with any previously created.

```
data _null_;
  file 'c:\temp\1.xlsx'; * just pretending;
  put '1';
  file 'c:\temp\2.xlsx'; * just pretending;
  put '2';
  file 'c:\temp\3.xlsx'; * just pretending;
  put '3';
run;

%let FP = c:\temp;

data _null_;
  length folderef fileref $8;
  rc = filename (folderef, "&FP");

  did = dopen(folderef);                               * open the folder;
  do _n_ = 1 to dnum(did);                             * loop over each file in folder;
    name = dread(did, _n_);                            * get filename name part only;
    if scan(name,-1,'.') = 'xlsx' then do;             * check for processing;
      rc = filename (fileref, "&FP./" || name);        * create fileref for fdelete;
      rc = fdelete(fileref);                           * delete xlsx;
      rc = filename (fileref);                         * clear fileref;
    end;
  end;
  did = dclose(did);                                   * close the folder;

  rc = filename (folderef);                            * clear the folder fileref;
run;
```